# Facebook invitation direct to broken link instead to google play

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the latest Facebook SDK in android to send invitation to my app but when the friends get the invitation and click on it they are directed to a facebook app broken page (page not found) instead to the google play for download. Anyone knows why?

Here is my code:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("message", message);
    bundle.putString("app_id", applicationId);

    if (friendId != null) {
        bundle.putString("to", friendId);
    }

    bundle.putString("title", title);

    WebDialog applicationInvitationDialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
            activity,
            ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            bundle
    )
            .setOnCompleteListener(
                    new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {
                        /**
                         *
                         * @param bundle
                         * @param facebookException
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle bundle, FacebookException facebookException) {

                            boolean wasSent = false;

                            if (facebookException != null) {

                                Configuration.singleton().getCrashReportHandler().logException(
                                        facebookException
                                );

                            } else {
                                wasSent = true;
                            }

                            callback.callback(
                                    wasSent, getInvitees(bundle)
                            );

                        }
                    }
            ).build();

    applicationInvitationDialog.show();
```

Comment: Are you using your google play app id instead of your facebook app id which references your google play app?

Comment: Oh ... you saying I should send the Google app id instead of the Facebook app id? ...

Comment: No the opposite, but looks like you have it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I don't need to send the app_id at all.
Hope it helps somebody.